# Javascript setInterval if statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

I've got a question:

if I use following code the `if` statement will never be executed:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
        // the date of new date is ofcourse a date in the future
        if (Date.now() == Date.parse(new Date(2014, 1, 13, 13, 4, 0, 0))){
            console.log('refresh done');
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
}, 1);
```

But if I change the `==` to `>=` it will execute correctly. Is this because the `Date.now()` will change so fast that it is changed before the comparison did took place?

Comment: But `Date.now()` is *not* `13. 1. 2014 13:04`. It's probably something more like `13.1. 2014 13:04:21.165`. You can't compare for equality if you don't expect the data will be equal :)

Comment: Yes, the interval happens a lot less often then the equality check. This is the reason. `Date.now()` works are a milisecond resolution http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range

Comment: @Luaan That's not true. Execute following code: `console.log(Date.now());` this will return a timestamp. @Benjamin Gruenbaum Ok, thank you for your answer. I already thought it had te be something like that :)

Comment: @GuyT So? The timestamp still has much more resolution than you want.

Comment: Most browsers don't support such fast timers for performance's sake. You'll probably get around 10ms between ticks. However, yesterday I was talking to someone that was fooling the browser into making super fast timers. :) In this case, though, you should probably just use `>=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that interval will run every 1ms, it depends on what else happens in loop, JS will only try to run it required amount of times when it comes to running it (I mean that if there was no time to run this function for one second JS will try to run it 1000 times after this time). Also I think there is minimal interval that will be forced and its more than one millisecond.